How to initialize c++ class member variables and shared_ptr as member variable?
I have a piece of c++ code:
//
//header file
//
class A
{
  public:
    A ();

};

class B 
{
  private:
   std::shared_ptr<A>  A_{nullptr} ;
  public:
    B(const std::shared_ptr<A>& mA);
};

In the body of implementation, I construct
B:B(const std::shared_ptr<A>& mA)
  A_(mA);

or
B:B(const std::shared_ptr<A>& mA)
  A_{mA};

It seems to me both constructor works, what are the difference between
() and {}

Is it usual to use shared_ptr for the member variable?

See Initialization on cppreference.com.  () is Direct-initialization, and {} is List-initialization. In any case, the syntax you showed is wrong, it should be more like B::B(const std::shared_ptr<A>& mA) : A_(mA) {} or B::B(const std::shared_ptr<A>& mA) : A_{mA} {}, see Constructors and member initializer lists

thanks for corrections. Do both initializations make a copy of object and assign to the member variable? Would it be better to use move,  A_=std::move(mA)  so that we can avoid assignment?

@CityOfHope Work on your presentation(s) (look at how the code is presented).  Also: One question per question.

"so that we can avoid assignment" - that will never happen. Move assignment is where another instance of a class take over overship of a resource. Nothing else. Nothing is moved or avoided. It's a contract.

@CityOfHope in this particular case, both will make a copy of the shared_ptr. Most of the time, it doesn't really matter whether you copy or move a shared_ptr due to its shared ownership semantics, but if you did want to move it then you have to change your constructor parameter to either std::shared_ptr<A> mA (pass by value) or std::shared_ptr<A>&& mA (pass by rvalue reference), since you can't move a const object.

The problem is probably that you actually don't do any initialization as you claim to do. As Remo suggests, use the initializer-list!

And to "Is it usual to use shared_ptr for the member variable?" - No, not at all. Motivate your every use of a shared_ptr.

sorry, did I understand this correctly: It is encouraged to use shared_ptr  for the member variable?

@CityOfHope "NO" - Hard no! Use it when you have a good reason to do so. It's an exception to the clear ownershipt idea.

Would it be usual/better to use raw pointer as member variable, like  A*  A_ ? Why it is not recommended to use shared_ptr as member variable?  It seems convenient to use shared_ptr instead of raw pointer?

@CityOfHope Ownership is key when it comes to programming "owning" stuff. shared_ptrs must be a layer above this, since, well, it's shared. Synchronizing actions on a shared resource is costly.
"convenient" doesn't matter. Do the right C++ thing. Own it, control it.

The only reason to have a pointer member is if you are storing a polymorphic type.  If you are then your go to should be std::unique_ptr<base_class_type>.  If you really need multiple objects to share the lifetime of the object, which as a member variable you shouldn't since the class owns the object, then you should use shared_p[tr. 90% pf the time you need a pointer it'll be a unique_ptr

I recommend using std::unique_ptr smart pointer for an owning pointer rather than a raw pointer that owns the object.  An owning raw pointer has to be properly coded to do the right thing for copy constructor, assignment, and destructor — which is easy to get wrong.  I recommend using std::shared_ptr only when you absolutely have to; the standard provides it because otherwise devs would just make their own smart shared pointer, and probably get it wrong more often than not.

You are doing this weird reference to s shared_ptr thing, which is entirely not MY thing. In general, when I want to copy a parameter, I usually take it by value so the caller decides how to create my copy. Which, of course, also means that I'm moving it into the instance variable. And, most of the time, when I don't want to keep a pointer, I pass a raw pointer anyway.

@ChristianStieber I'm a bit confused about " I usually take it by value so the caller decides how to create my copy" etc. In my world the caller decides nothing. It's a hard compilation error (when failing to comply).

@TedLyngmo that may be your world. In my world, if I take a const std::string& just to make a copy, I feel that's inefficient: like when the caller wants to move some of his data to me, he'd have to create a string first, and then I'd copy that string. What a waste. If I take a std::string, the caller has full flexibility how he wants to produce that, and I just move the string I get into my storage. Same thing there: if I want to store a shared_ptr, I ask the caller to give me one; I don't ask for a reference to an existing one.

@ChristianStieber,  oh, I thought using const std::string& is to copy of reference to the object, that is similar to copy of a pointer to the object. There seems no copy of object itself. it shall be cheap. I might totally misunderstand.

@Eljay in most cases, I don't usually think of "ownership" when I use a shared_ptr -- more often than not, it's a "producer" and an arbitrary number of "users". The producer can even throw away the data without having to be concerned about whether someone might still be using it -- either because it's fleeting (like messages on a message hub) so the producer never kept it anyway, or because new data has come in to replace the old.

@CityOfHope yes, a reference does not copy the object. I was specifically talking about cases where I want a copy of the object, like the guy with the question and his std::shared_ptr instance variables; these are not references, so at some point he'll have to make a copy of the parameter.

@ChristianStieber I must i admit I stopped reading at ", if I take a const std::string& just to make a copy, I feel that's inefficient:" - because you missed everything. That's one overload.  Promoting shared_ptr as an alternative sounds like terrible advice.

@ChristianStieber Oh, ok, I got it:  @ChristianStieber:  " I don't usually think of "ownership" when I use a shared_ptr" - Quite an expensive way of doing any low level stuff.

@ChristianStieber Coming back to the first, it's also not copying expensively like your shared_ptrinitiaive does. Not a good idea.

@NathanOliver Yes, I use the pointer for a polymorphic type member variable.  I was using shared_ptr due to the reason that the object pointed by this shared_ptr is used/shared by other  classes as well.  But I may totally misunderstand the meaning of "shared" in the shared_ptr . If I use std::unique_ptr, would it be a problem since only this class has its ownship?

@CityOfHope That is something you will have to determine yourself.  You need to ask yourself who participates in the ownership of the pointer.  If the pointer should only live as long as the class does and then that means the class should be the sole owner of the pointer and you want a unique_ptr.  If other objects share how long the pointer should live then that is a case for a shared_ptr.

Thanks all.  This is really a great help
